# How do I convert a C# object into a Javascript array of arrays using JSON?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to convert an object of the following C# class type into a Javascript array of arrays:

```
public class SankeyData
{
  public string Source { get; set; }
  public int Width { get; set; }
  public string Destination { get; set; }
}
```

The array of arrays in Javascript needs to look like this:

```
[["Link1",10,"Link2"],["Link3",20,"Link4"],["Link5",30,"Link6"]]
```

Is there an easy way to do the conversion?  I'm using a jQuery `$.getJSON` to get the data from a C# controller action.

My related technologies include MVC5, jQuery, and JSON.  I've tried using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, but the data won't come over correctly.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$.getJSON('/Application/Sankey', { id: @Model.ID }, function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (i, item) {
    sankey.setData(JSON.stringify(item));
  });
});
```

Which gives a close result, but not quite what I need:

```
[{"Source":"Link1","Width":10,"Destination":"Link2"},{"Source":"Link3","Width":20,"Destination":"Link4"},{"Source":"Link5","Width":30,"Destination":"Link6"}]
```

**NOTE**:  I'm already using an MVC `@model` for something else in the page so I can't just set the `@model` to the `SankeyData` class.

Comment: Just put them in the array and then serialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way out there to serialized C# objects to JSON Array. You can achieve this either

- By converting C# objects to C# Array and then serialise the array as JSON.
- Use Javascript to convert serialised objects to JSON Array.

I would recommend second option as array is heterogeneous.

Something like this:

```js
function objectsToArray(data, columns) {
  var dataArray = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var itemArray = [];
    for (var j in columns) {
      itemArray.push(data[i][columns[j]]);
    }
    dataArray.push(itemArray);
  }
  return dataArray;
}

data = [{"Source":"Link1","Width":10,"Destination":"Link2"},{"Source":"Link3","Width":20,"Destination":"Link4"},{"Source":"Link5","Width":30,"Destination":"Link6"}]

console.log(objectsToArray(data, ["Source", "Width", "Destination"]));
```

So, just pull data using `$.getJSON` and the feed to `objectsToArray` with key names in order. Hope that solves your problem.